# Proof involving a summation: $\sum_{i<j}(x_i +x_j) = (n-1)\sum x_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, summation

How would I go about proving that 
$\sum_{i<j} 1 $ = $ n\choose 2$

and $$ \sum_{i<j}(x_i +x_j) = (n-1)\sum x_i $$
I understand the intuition behind the statements. I'm just unsure of how to proceed with proving this

Comment: Have you tried recursion ?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint 1:** In the identity $\sum_{i<j} {1} = {n \choose 2}$, it seems that the sum goes on the number of $(i,j)$ pairs such that $i,j\in \mathbb{N}$ and $1\le i<j\le n$. For every such pairs you need to choose two elements from the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

**Hint 2:** In the identity $\sum_{i<j}(x_i +x_j) = (n-1)\sum x_i$, it seems that there is a set $$X=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$$ and the sum $\sum_{i<j}(x_i +x_j)$ goes on all **2-element** subsets of $X$. Now if you consider any $x_i$, it could be in $(n-1)$ such subsets of $X$.

Comment: Dear Ethan, the second statement is not false, for some visualization just consider the set $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$, then the summation $\sum_{i<j}(x_i +x_j)$ is $(x_1+x_2)+(x_1+x_3)+(x_2+x_3)$ and as we can see there is two ($=3-1$) of each $x_i$.

Comment: Dear Ethan, your answer is totally true, just note that in the identity $$\sum_{(i,j)\in Q^2}_{i<j}(x_i+x_j)=\sum_{(i,j)\in Q^2}x_i-\sum_{i\in Q}x_i$$ the summation $\sum_{(i,j)\in Q^2}x_i$ equals $n\sum_{i\in Q}x_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$. The second identity is counting the sum of all 2-subsets of $X $ and can be proven using induction on $n$, the size of the set. We omit the base case. Suppose the following equality holds for some set $X$ of $n$ elements:
$$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(x_i+x_j)=(n-1)\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}x_i$$
then we consider the set $X':=X\cup \{x_{n+1}\}$.

The sum of all 2-subsets of $X'$ is 
\begin{align*}\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n+1}(x_i+x_j)&=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(x_i+x_j)+\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}(x_i+x_{n+1})\\
&=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(x_i+x_j)+\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}x_i+nx_{n+1}\\
&=(n-1)\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}x_i+\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}x_i+nx_{n+1}\\
&=n\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}x_i+nx_{n+1}\\
&=n\sum_{1\leq i\leq n+1}x_i
\end{align*}
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

For both problems, I would start out with calculating the sum for all $0 \le i,j \le n$.  You can then partition all the $(i,j)$ pairs into subsets with $i \lt j$, $i = j$, and $i > j$.  The $i=j$ partition is easy to calculate, and the $i > j$ partition will be equal to the $i < j$ partition due to symmetry.  Since $S = S_{i<j} + S_{i=j} + S_{i\gt j} = 2S_{i<j} + S_{i=j}$, $S_{i\lt j} = \dfrac{S - S_{i=j}}2$.

Comment: Based on your comment, I'm wondering this is true for all summation questions involving symmetry. Would $\sum_{i \neq j} = 2\sum_{i<j}$  hold in all problems like this?

Comment: When you're calculating $\sum{f(i,j)}$ and $f(i,j) = f(j,i)$, then yes.